# Why does my code terminate when I add a 7th character to my array?

Tags: c, arrays

When I initialize my arrays "temp" and "string" I expect them to be able to hold strings up to length 1000 because I initialize them with MAXLEN which holds the value 1000. However, when I enter a string that is greater than the first one I entered I receive the message:

Command terminated

I believe the error is in the copy function, but I don't understand where or why it is happening.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLEN 1000


int longestLine(char s[]);
void copy(char to[], char from[]);

// prints the longest line, and length of the longest line
int main()
{
    int max;
    char string[MAXLEN];

    max = longestLine(string); 

    printf("max length is %d\n", max);
    printf("%s\n", string);

    return 0;
}

// returns the longest line in an input
int longestLine(char s[])
{
    int max, cnt, c;
    char temp[MAXLEN];

    max = cnt = 0;
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
            if (c == '\n')
            {
                   if (cnt > max)
                   {
                        max = cnt;
                        copy(s, temp);
                   }
                   cnt = -1; //if newline reset count
            }
            temp[cnt] = c;
            cnt++;
    }

    return max;
}

// copys array contents from "from" to "to"
void copy(char to[], char from[])
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; from[i] != '\0'; ++i)
   {
       to[i] = from[i];
   }   }
```

With the input:

```
this is line one
this is line two which is longer
```

This is the expected output:

```
max length is 32
this is line two which is longer
```

This is the actual output:

```
Command terminated
```

Thank you for the help!

EDIT:

Figured it out, the line cnt=-1 was messing me up. Thank you!

Comment: Well, your copy function reads `from` which is instantiated on the stack in `longestLine` but never given an initial value.

Comment: `cnt = -1; ... temp[cnt] = c;` That's a bad idea.

Comment: When I call copy though, I pass it the array temp as from and the array temp is initialized. I may be missing something as I'm quite new to c. Thank you very much for the quick reply.

Comment: `temp` is not null terminated. But your `copy` function expects it to be.

Comment: (a) you need an `else` in here. and (b) if `copy` expects a terminated string, you had better make sure it gets one.

Comment: I see. Everything makes a lot of sense, except the else. Why do I need else?

Comment: It's just one way of doing this, rather than using `continue` (i.e. a glorified `goto`). Example [here](https://pastebin.com/nhGrpwSK).

Comment: Hi @AviouslyAK, welcome to SO! I would encourage you to use standard library functions such as `strcpy(dest, src)` from the `string.h` header file! Don't reinvent the wheel, but if you did it for getting a hang of C, no problem. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. You do not assign '\0' as the last element in temp. Hence, the for loop in the copy function might run forever. Add a '\0' to the last entry within the if block before calling the copy function.
2. Even If your input does have a '\0' at the end, you reset cnt to -1 within the if block. But the moment it steps out of the if statement, your code ends up assigning tmp[-1] a value. Use a continue statement at the end of the if block.